# Filter a tuple with values from a list

Tags: python

I have the following dataset:

```
test_set = ("The sun in the sky", "The sun in the light", "Do not blame it on moonlight", "Do not blame it on sunshine")
```

What I would like to do now if filter this test based on a list. So like

```
y = [0,1]
test_set_2 = test_set[y]
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/marcvanderpeet/PycharmProjects/untitled/test3.py", line 5, in <module>
test_set_2 = test_set[y]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not list
```

Any ideas on how I can get the result I am looking for:

```
test_set_2 = ("The sun in the sky", "The sun in the light")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run through the index list and extract the relevant item from the big list.

```
test_set = ("The sun in the sky", "The sun in the light", "Do not blame it on moonlight", "Do not blame it on sunshine")

y = [0,1]
test_set_2 =  tuple([test_set[index] for index in y])

print test_set_2
```